# How to get date format as "yyyy mm/dd"?

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird-3.0

I am trying to output a time stamp field from view in this format `yyyy mm/dd` so I tried like this:

```
extract(year from mytable.order_date)||' '||extract(month from mytable.order_date)||'/'||extract(day from mytable.order_date),
```

however there is no padding zeros so how I add them ?

using Firebird 3.0

Comment: Cannot you use to_char? to_char(order_date, 'YYYY MM/DD')

Comment: @Avani `to_char` is Oracle specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [`lpad`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref30/firebird-30-language-reference.html#fblangref30-scalarfuncs-lpad) function to pad with `0`, ie

```
extract(year from mytable.order_date) ||' '||
   lpad(extract(month from mytable.order_date), 2, '0')||'/'||
   lpad(extract(day from mytable.order_date), 2, '0')
```